# Trying to populate a list from resultset size is around 12000 rows on executing action again for about 4 times,jvm gets out of heap memory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, heap-memory, heap-size

I am trying to populate an arraylist of type tableList with database with around 12000 records  and then populating my jsp page with the use of struts iterator tag,but on executing this action again and again the jvm gets out of memory and as seen by me the heap size keep on decreasing every time i call this action from my page.I consider that the list space is not deallocated whenever a new instance of this action class is created.suggest the solution for this problem .I am also running tableList.clear(); in the constructor of the class

```
int records=0;
        spl("BEFORE: "+run.freeMemory()+"-"+run.totalMemory()+"-"+run.maxMemory());//spl is for system.out.println and run is an object of Runtime class
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            records++;
            if(!resultSet.getString("service_date").equals("N/A"))
            {
                serviceYear=resultSet.getString("service_date").split("-");
                regnNumber=officeCode+"/"+resultSet.getString("serviceid_requested")+"/"+resultSet.getString("country_code")+"/"+resultSet.getString("service_file_srno")+"/"+serviceYear[2];
            }
            else
            {
                regnNumber=officeCode+"/"+resultSet.getString("serviceid_requested")+"/"+resultSet.getString("country_code")+"/"+resultSet.getString("service_file_srno")+"/0000";
            }
            tableList.add(new MISTable(regnNumber,resultSet.getString("given_name"),resultSet.getString("surname"),
                                        resultSet.getString("nationality"),resultSet.getString("service_date"),resultSet.getString("service_expiry_date"),
                                        resultSet.getString("passport_number"),resultSet.getString("passport_expiry_date"),resultSet.getString("visa_number"),
                                        resultSet.getString("visa_expiry_date"),resultSet.getString("visa_type"),"")
                                        );
        }
        spl("AFTER: "+run.freeMemory()+"-"+run.totalMemory()+"-"+run.maxMemory());
```

Comment: better to use pagination , something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase java memory arguments for running the application.

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

You can set maximum memory for java...

Answer (score 0):

Use [**pagination**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) !

You can load the entire List and show only one page (let's say 10 records) in the page (better with a cache),
OR (a lot better) load just the part of the resultset that you need to show, limiting the results with SQL.

Loading 12000 records and dumping them in a page is **wrong**, it overloads the server, the client and by the way who wanna read (or scroll) a web page 
*tall* like a building ?

Comment: I know, thats what i am doing right now i just want to know why the jvm memory does not gets returned to heap after instantiating a new class and is there any way to clear it in my action class because the .clear method seems of no use as i think list from previous instantiation remains in the heap...and only list reference is deallocated and not the references it contains to th MISTable objects in it.

Comment: Set all the stuff to null (and close those who need to be closed, obviously). That way you tell Garbage Collector to collect them ASAP.